# Limited factor loading output in python factor-analyzer

Tags: python, factor-analysis

I am new here but I hope you guys can help me out.

I'm trying to conduct factor analysis with word vectors in python using the Factor-Analyzer module. I have a DataFrame with
[100 columns and more than 15,000 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkrcl.png).

I did not receive any error when I performed a factor analysis. Below is the output:

```
FactorAnalyzer(bounds=(0.005, 1), impute='median', is_corr_matrix=False,
               method='minres', n_factors=10, rotation='varimax',
               rotation_kwargs={}, use_smc=True)
```

But when I try to get the loadings, it only returns [100 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZzFC.png). I want to get the loadings for all rows.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import pickle
factor_df = pd.read_pickle("word_vectors.pkl")
factor_df = pd.DataFrame(data=factor_df)

fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=10, rotation='varimax')
fa.fit(factor_df)

loading = fa.loadings_
loadings_df = pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_)
loadings_df
```

The pickle file for my dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HenU04VxtFkBuihvl7nUYRhLy5mRLqdQ/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Factor loadings are the weights and correlations between each variable (column in your DataFrame) and the factor, so the `fa.loadings_` object is an array with shape `(number_of_variables, number_of_factors)` - in your example `(100, 10)`.

If you would like to get transformed DataFrame with only 10 columns in each row, you should call `fa.transform(factor_df)` after `fa.fit(factor_df)`. Returned array will have shape `(number_of_rows, number_of_factors)` - in your example `(15_000, 10)`.